# Error with using IPOPT in Python on Windows and NEOS server

Tags: python, pyomo, ipopt

I'm trying to run a code for a complex model, which was translated from GAMS to Python (DICE16). It needs pyomo and ipopt, but there is a problem with ipopt on Windows 10 (64-bit), as conda-forge only installs the version 3.10.1, which doesn't work with my code:

```
ERROR: Solver (ipopt) returned non-zero return code (1)
ERROR: Solver log: Ipopt 3.11.1: halt_on_ampl_error=yes acceptable_tol=1e-08
    constr_viol_tol=1e-10 max_iter=2000 bound_frac=0.1


    **************************************************************************
        **** This program contains Ipopt, a library for large-scale nonlinear
        optimization.
     Ipopt is released as open source code under the Eclipse Public License
     (EPL).
             For more information visit http://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt
    **************************************************************************
        ****

    NOTE: You are using Ipopt by default with the MUMPS linear solver.
          Other linear solvers might be more efficient (see Ipopt
          documentation).


    This is Ipopt version 3.11.1, running with linear solver mumps.

    Number of nonzeros in equality constraint Jacobian...:     6445 Number of
    nonzeros in inequality constraint Jacobian.:        0 Number of nonzeros
    in Lagrangian Hessian.............:      984

    Error evaluating constraint 901: can't compute 0/0.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ApplicationError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-759fa6ac1706> in <module>
      3 with open("DICE16_PF.py") as f:
      4     code = compile(f.read(), "DICE16_PF.py", 'exec')
----> 5     exec(code)
      6

~\Desktop\VKR\DICE16_PF.py in <module>
    575         solver.options['bound_frac'] = 0.1
    576         #solver.options['bound_relax_factor'] = 0
--> 577         results = solver.solve(m)#,tee=True)
    578         print(sorted(m.t))
    579         print(m.OBJ.expr.value)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py in solve(self, *args, **kwds)
    598                     logger.error("Solver log:\n" + str(_status.log))
    599                 raise pyutilib.common.ApplicationError(
--> 600                     "Solver (%s) did not exit normally" % self.name)
    601             solve_completion_time = time.time()
    602             if self._report_timing:

ApplicationError: Solver (ipopt) did not exit normally
```

This code works on Linux or IOS, as they have the latest versions of IPOPT, so the code doesn't involve division by 0.

I tried to use IPOPT through the NEOS server, but it didn't work, too:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-759fa6ac1706> in <module>
      3 with open("DICE16_PF.py") as f:
      4     code = compile(f.read(), "DICE16_PF.py", 'exec')
----> 5     exec(code)
      6

~\Desktop\VKR\DICE16_PF.py in <module>
    575         # solver.options['bound_frac'] = 0.1
    576         # #solver.options['bound_relax_factor'] = 0
--> 577         results = solver.solve(m)#,tee=True)
    578         print(sorted(m.t))
    579         print(m.OBJ.expr.value)

NameError: name 'solver' is not defined
```

I also tried to change the name of solver to IPOPT, Ipopt or even conopt and bonmin, but the problem remains the same.

Here's the part of the code, where I use Ipopt (or conopt):
[part of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVKCl.png)

What should I do to fix this?
I'm new to all of this, so I'm sorry if my question sounds silly.

Comment: In the error message you posted it looks like you're missing the line `solver = SolverFactory('ipopt')` but I do see this line in the picture you posted. I see Ipopt 3.11.1 on conda-forge so I suggest you try uninstalling and reinstalling ipopt through conda. You can also check for search path issues by running the command `solver.available()` in Python once you have ipopt installed.

Comment: I tried reinstalling IPOPT and Anaconda itself several times, it didn't fix anything. Also I tried your recommended command and it returns True. But thanks for trying!

Comment: Can you reformulate the constraint to avoid the 0/0 and/or initialize your variables so that the constraint expression doesn't evaluate to 0/0? If you aren't sure which constraint it is you can use the following option to preserve the constraint names: `solver.solve(m, tee=True, symbolic_solver_labels=True)`

Comment: I tried to, but it didn't work